# The Android API Guides are a little unclear to me about the android:onClick XML attribute

Tags: android, xml, button, checkbox, onclick

In the [Android API Guides for checkboxes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox.html), they state that you can set an attribute in a layout's XML (`android:onClick`) to launch a designated method. The same is said in [the guide for Buttons](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html), but the guide for buttons also has this bit:

> You can also declare the click event handler pragmatically rather than in an XML layout. This might be necessary if you instantiate the `Button` at runtime or you need to declare the click behavior in a `Fragment` subclass.

This raises the following question: Can you or can you not take advantage of the `android:onClick` attribute if the button or checkbox is found in a Fragment? If so, I would assume the method to be called would be declared in the Fragment, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize the `onClick` attribute in fragments. However, since a `Fragment` is part of an `Activity`, the designated method will be launched in the Activity class, not in the fragment.

Comment: Well, that's annoying. I'll have to define it twice since I have multiple layouts depending on form factor. Well, I could do it twice in the activities and once in the fragment, and have the activities call the fragment's method. Still a nuisance.

Comment: Agreed, it's definitely less than ideal. I've used a pattern the defines onClick in all Fragments and FragmentActivities and lets the Activity fire the Fragments' onClick. The onClick dispatches the event through the View's id. XML points to the onClick for all buttons -- this avoids having to assign the onClickListeners, but I hesitate to publish it here because it doesn't seem elegant. Might need to look into RoboGuice or other injection-based approaches.

Answer (score 3):

The target method for `android:onClick` should be defined in the activity that host the fragments.